# no me funciona AJAX de jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

cabe aclarar que soy nuevo en php y jquery, he intentado varias cosas y no me funciono ninguna...
lo que quiero hacer es que cuando hago click en una fila de una tabla que previamente cargo del servido, quiero que me pase esa informacion de la fila a otra pagina y esos valores los cargo en variables para despues hacer un echo dentro de labels...todo parece funcionar bien, de hecho no arroja error y sale por el .done, pero al parecer la variable superglobal $_POST dice que esta indefinida, por lo que interpreto como vacia...
les paso parte del codigo
aclaro que los enlaces a jquery y el codigo script estan antes de la etiqueta de cierre del body...

este es el codigo script.

```
      <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
      <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


      <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {

      $('.BusquedaRapida tr').click(function(){

           var nombre = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
           var direccion = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html();
           var telefono = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html();
           var correo = $(this).find('td:eq(4)').html();
           var localidad = $(this).find('td:eq(5)').html();

         $.ajax({

                url:'historial_clientes.php',
                type:'post',
                data: {nom: nombre,
                      direc: direccion,
                      tel: telefono,
                      cor: correo,
                      loc: localidad},
              })
             .done(function(respuesta) {
                 $(location).attr('href','historial_clientes.php');
             })
              .fail(function() {
                  console.log('Error');   })
             });
    });
```

si hago un console.log de las variables las imprime perfectamente antes de pasar a la pagina historial_clientes y si hago console.log de respuesta, me trae todo el html de la pagina historial_clientes, no se si eso es correcto...por consola no arroja ningun error!!

la pagina receptora tiene el siguiente codigo de encabezado...

```
     <?php
     require 'encabezado.php';
     require 'config.php';

      $nombre1 ="";
      $direccion1 ="";
      $telefono1 ="";
      $correo1 ="";
      $localidad1 ="";

      if (isset($_POST['nombre'])) {

         $nombre1 = $_POST['nombre'];
         $direccion1 = $_POST['direccion'];
         $telefono1 = $_POST['telefono'];
         $correo1 = $_POST['correo'];
         $localidad1 = $_POST['localidad'];
    }else{
        echo "No se puede realizar la accion solicitada";
    }

    ?>
```

siempre sale por el else.... y lo que haria mas abajo es en los labels que nombre anteriormente hago un echo de las variables a las que les otorgo el valor de $_POST...

agradezco de antemano cualquier asesoramiento y este blog es el mas completo de los que he visitado... gracias!!

Comment: Envías como parámetro `nom` y estás buscando `nombre`. Y en los otros campos igual. Utiliza los nombres correctos. `$_POST['nom'];`

Comment: En la super global los índices son los valores que usaste a la izquierda en el objeto `data` de jQuery, o sea, `nom, direc, tel` etc. Eso podrás verlo si haces un `var_dump($_POST);` Por otra parte, algo que es rarísimo en tu código que es que en el `done` hagas un location al mismo archivo destinatario de la petición Ajax. Eso no tiene sentido. En el `done` se suele recibir la respuesta del servidor para usarla en el cliente.

Comment: hago un location porque quiero ir a esa pagina despues de que me pase por post las variables (cuando hago click en la tabla, quiero que me pase los valores de la fila en cuestion e ir a la pagina historial_clientes.php con esos valores seleccionados en las variables....por eso hago el location). Ahi corregí lo que me dijeron pero igualmente no me funciona cuando hago el var_dump de $_POST me dice que es un array vacio. Se entendio mas o menos que es lo que quiero hacer?

Comment: No tiene sentido volver a llamar en el `done` la misma página que usas para recibir/procesar los datos. Al querer hacer eso es evidente que ignoras un punto esencial de Ajax: cuando la petición Ajax se hace ya comunica con esa página, pasándole los valores que mandas en el parámetro `data`. Luego, lo que debe ocurrir en `historial_clientes.php` es que recibas los datos, los proceses y devuelvas una respuesta a Ajax, que recibirías en el `done`, luego allí trabajas con esa respuesta. Hacer un `location` en el `done` es como ir de América a Australia a buscar algo, volver a América con lo ...

Comment: ... que trajiste de Australia, para no hacer nada con eso y volver de nuevo a Australia a buscar lo que ya trajiste. No sé si me explico. Ajax es para comunicar entre cliente y servidor en la misma petición hecha, recibiendo los datos en la respuesta, no volviendo desde la respuesta (`done`)  a buscar lo que ya ha sido respondido (volver otra vez a Australia a buscar algo que ya trajiste).

Comment: Cedano....entiendo lo que decís, entonces no es Ajax en si mismo lo que necesito...pude resolverlo recién pasando el ID del cliente por get y en la página receptora volviendo a consultar la base de datos y recogiendo los valores restantes de la base de datos, es un poco más largo, pero funcionó, voy a tener que revisar y entender mejor Ajax entonces....gracias por el aporte!!

Answer (score -1):

En la petición AJAX estás pasando los siguientes campos:

```
data: {
    nom: nombre,
    direc: direccion,
    tel: telefono,
    cor: correo,
    loc: localidad},
}
```

Sin embargo, en el archivo PHP que recibe la petición, estás leyendo estos campos:

```
$nombre1 = $_POST['nombre'];
$direccion1 = $_POST['direccion'];
$telefono1 = $_POST['telefono'];
$correo1 = $_POST['correo'];
$localidad1 = $_POST['localidad'];
```

Es decir, los nombres de los campos no coinciden (por ejemplo, **nom** no es igual a **nombre**). Por lo que siempre te va a devolver "No se puede realizar la accion solicitada".

Comment: Eso lo corregí eduardo pero igual no me funcionó...